# How to implement Angular Router animation in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, ionic3, angular-animations

Recently Angulater added a feature by which we can easily implement animation when entering a view.
My qs is how can I implement this feature in ionic?

You can find more about router transition [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-supercharge-your-router-transitions-using-new-animation-features-v4-3-3eb341ede6c8)

My goal is to set custom transition when I push a new page. More precisely, I want to implement the rightmost design in ionic which you can find [here](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/landing-experiments-sources-sorted-by-complexity-template)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Angular Router transitions using new animation features on `v4.3+` since `Ionic 3` uses Angular `4.1.3`

But you can use `Angular Web Animations API` to do the animation. But keep in mind you must get the right version since Ionic is behind the Angular.

```
npm install @angular/animations@4.1.3 --save --save-exact
```

Here is an [**article about it**](https://www.joshmorony.com/add-to-cart-with-the-web-animations-api-in-ionic/).

Comment: Even if Ionic would already use version `4.3+` of Angular this will not be possible because Ionic is using its own router called NavController which is optimized for mobile apps.

Comment: thanks for the answer and comment. But I need to implement custom page transition. Is there any way to do that in ionic?

Comment: You can have a look at this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions/